# Solving Integration with exponentials

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve this integration :

```
Integrate[(1 - Exp[-a*x])* (1 - Exp[-b*x])*(1 - Exp[-c*x]), {x, 0, t}]
```

I get the result. But when I use the below expression to see step-by-step calculations, I don't get any result:

```
WolframAlpha["integrate[(1 - Exp[-a*x])* (1- Exp[-b*x])*(1 - \
Exp[-c*x]), {x, 0, t}]", 
 PodStates -> {"definiteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: For many integrals there is simply no easy step-by-step way of solving the integral. Internally it might convert it to a very generalized function, integrate it, and then convert it back to conventional mathematical functions (Cos, Sin, Tan, Exp etc).

Comment: When I change to an indefinite integral I see steps. So I will venture to guess @SHuisman is quite right, and this class of definite integrals does not support the "show steps" capability.

Comment: Also: When I change {a,b,c} to {1,2,3} respectively I do get steps to appear. Possibly [dancing to the Jackson Five](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho7796-au8U)